# Wifi networking on android?

Tags: android, networking, wifi

I want to connect two android phones via a socket using wifi is it possible? please help

Answer (score 0):

You will need to work with sockets, it's not that hard, you can get a really good tutorial on this link:

[Working with sockets](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-1996/jw-12-sockets.html)

Comment: thank you for your response. I have worked with java sockets. the problem i have is connecting two android devices with wifi in access point mode so i just wanted to know is there a special way of doing so when using wifi :)